# Djnago 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Actually i'm trying to update user profile but when i try to update it it show's the error.

**AttributeError at /user/profile/
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute '_meta'**
After searching so many solution i can't get rid of it. I am messing with my code from 24hrs.
Please help me to get rid of this.

***-- My code is ---***
**Views.py**

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method=='POST':

        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfilePicUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile_image)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile Updated Succesfully')
            redirect('profile/')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfilePicUpdateForm()

    context = {'u_form': u_form,'p_form':p_form}
    
    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = KeepSafeUserModel
        fields = ['username','email','first_name','last_name']
class ProfilePicUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = KeepSafeUserModel
        fields = ['profile_image']
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
# ///////////////User Manager/////////////////////
# Create your models here.
# overriding the create and superuser function

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,username,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users Must Have email Address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users Must Have username")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,

        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,username,password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True 
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
         

# ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def get_profile_image_filepath(self,filename):
    return f'profile_images/{self.pk/{profile_image.png}}' #pk= primary key


def get_default_profile_image():
    return "img/default_profile/default.png"

class KeepSafeUserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='first_name',max_length=30,default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='last_name',max_length=30,default="")
    email= models.TextField(verbose_name='email',max_length=60,unique=True,primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined",auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login',auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=225,upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath,null=True,blank=True,default=get_default_profile_image)
    #password field is buil-in
    # hide_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_Label):
        return True
        
    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        return str(self.profile_image)[str(self.profile_image).index('profile_images/{self.pk}/')]
```

Comment: does your 'profile.html' file have a `profile_image ._meta` in it somewhere?

Comment: no it doesn't contain any ._meta.

Answer (score 0):

So after messing with up my code i got my answer by my own. Actually the problem is with the forms. If you see in the above code i have created two different forms from same model.
But when i try to submit that form always an exception is burning my mind that no _meta and all. After finding more solution i successfully removed it but some other exceptions is stopping me to fix the whole bug. Then i noticed one thing that why i've created two form why not one. {well i am learning from a video so i just did the same steps} so i think i should use only one form for both operations and i just used this.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = KeepSafeUserModel
        fields = ['username','email','first_name','last_name','profile_image']
```

and you won't believe the code worked succesfully.
If someone knows a better way to solve this please answer so all dev's like us get the solution.

Comment: Yup and thanks for taking interest in this question.